# Error while trying to install an npm module from git

Tags: node.js, git, npm, module

I forked and module on Github, changed it for my needs and pushed back to git. Now I am trying to install this module with npm with

`npm install git+http://github.com/username/modulename.git`

But I get the following error:

`npm ERR! Command failed: git submodule update -q --init --recursive
npm ERR! fatal: O:/Programs/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.`

What can cause it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this is similar [to this thread](https://npm.community/t/any-clue-why-npm-would-start-giving-err-fatal-git-submodule-cannot-be-used-without-a-working-tree-errors/2431):

> After a bit of debugging, I have determined that this actually works if I use the url "https://github.com/nfroidure/ttf2woff2#master" instead.
>   This is because it is doing a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt), which doesn’t use [`--mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---mirror), so isn’t a bare repository.

So in your case:

```
npm install "https://github.com/username/modulename.git#master"
```